# Way to see better error message - LWC useless error on Lightning_RecordPage

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image: useless error message screenshot]

Is there a way to see what the true error is behind this? This is thrown when an LWC (assuming invalid in some way) is added to a Lightning Record Page.

The component is hitting a custom apex method that has been tested in a SF Community (and is working fine, and when it isn't, the error reporting is much nicer). The apex method is using `without sharing`, and has been switched out with simpler methods that merely return a hardcoded string, just to make sure the apex code isn't the issue here.

Static LWCs that don't query for data seem to be working fine, but that's not very useful. It seems building LWCs for Lightning_RecordPage targets seem to be a lot more 'touchy' and prone to just falling over without telling you exactly why.

So, just wondering if there is somewhere these errors are properly reported? The console isn't useful at all - `The Notification permission may only be requested from inside a short running user-generated event handler.` is the best we get, which looks like a generic error of no use.

Comment: Does your user have permissions to Apex class that acts as a controller for your LWC? It is obligatory to add the access to @AuraEnabled methods for Authenticated users since Winter '20: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_restrict_apex_authenticated_users.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a case of attempting to import `@salesforce/community/*` based code in the LWCs.

```js
import communityId from '@salesforce/community/Id'
import communityBasePath from '@salesforce/community/basePath'
```

dropping these solved the issues when attempting to use the LWCs in Lightning Record Pages.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_salesforce_modules